# Won't import local file as module

Tags: python, flask

I'm setting up a Flask application on Digitalocean and have Python 3.7 installed and the latest version of Flask. When running the app inside a virtualenv and trying to run the application using `python3.7 application.py` I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "application.py", line 11, in <module>
        from config import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

What puzzles me is that config.py is located in the same folder as application.py, and not in a subfolder. I have duplicated the setup on my local machine, also running Python 3.7 and inside a virtualenv, and the importing (and the app) works flawlessly.

I've tried importing "config.py" instead of just "config" but didn't make a difference. I also tried specifying exactly what it should import (instead of using '*') but that didn't make a difference either.

Your thoughts on why it can't find config?

Comment: if you open up a python shell in the folder are you able to import config properly on your Digital ocean instance?

Comment: Yeah, works just fine. But not in virtualenv

Comment: And to clarify, it works fine in the Python shell in that folder, but if I run the same .py in virtualenv, or if I use Python shell from within the virtualenv, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to have been the solution to my problem above was to run the Python shell and add the path to the directory in which `config.py` is located (even though it's in the same folder as application.py...) by using the following command:

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/config/")
```